# PHP Check if get url has number on specific spot in the url

Tags: php

This is what I am currently using to check the incoming get request

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'GET' && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'api/rooms/1/messages') !== false) { 

}
```

as you can see the rooms number is hardcoded I only need to check if it is a number at all on that specific spot between rooms/ and /messages how can I achieve this

Comment: So split the string up using `explode()` and check the bits

Comment: I would recommend that you look into using a router. Then you can easily set up specific routes (including dynamic values in the URL) for specific http methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use `preg_match`.
Instead of doing:

```
strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'api/rooms/1/messages') !== false
```

You could do:

```
preg_match("/api\/rooms\/[0-9]+\/messages/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```